# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework- InvalidOperationException in dbModel context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I got the error when initialize the dbModel context as follows:

[image]

This is my `dbContext` class:

```
public class DbModel : DbContext
{
    public DbModel()
    {
    }

    public DbModel(DbContextOptions<DbModel> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<UserModel> User {get;set;}
}
```

I added the following code in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` according to some answers in stackoverflow, but I'm still getting an error.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

This is my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMvc();
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.Restaurant;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<DbModel>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Restaurant APIs", Description = "Swagger Core API" });
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    }
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manually initializing `DbModel` instead of using DI to inject it into your controller.

```
public ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbModel _db;

    public ValuesController(DbModel db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct.`DbContext` initialization needs to inject dependencies from the container.So you can't directly use new.